# Java collect Map of Sets

Tags: java

I have a set of maps

```
Set<Map<String, Set<String>>>
```

I would like, using java streams, to combine all the maps in the set into one where the keys are all the keys of the maps and the values the union of the sets which are associated to the same key.

Output:

```
Ma<String, Set<String>>
```

Example input:

```
[
 {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [2,3,4]
 },
 {
  a: [4,5,6]
 }
]
```

Example output:

```
{
 a: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 b: [2,3,4]
}
```

I tried some solution but so far not solved yet

Comment: And what is the problem? Did you try anything? Did you encounter any issues while doing it?

Comment: I am trying to do it and so far no progress

Comment: Your question reads like written by a 1 day newbie, not a 9 year member of this community. The idea is to *include* your own efforts, instead of simply dumping your requirements here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Stream of all the entries of all the inner maps, and collect them to a single map:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> output =
    input.stream()
         .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                   Map.Entry::getValue,
                                   (v1,v2) -> {v1.addAll(v2); return v1;}));
```

Comment: I enjoy the use of `flatMap()`. It's clever.